# Find duplicate names within an array of different files

Tags: javascript, reactjs, loops, if-statement, recursion

A bit of a different use case from the ones I was suggested above.
I need to loop through and check each file name within an array of files and push the files that have the same name into a new array so that I can upload them later separately.

This is my code so far, and surely I have a problem with my conditional checking, can somebody see what I am doing wrong?

```
filesForStorage = [
{id: 12323, name: 'name', ...},
{id: 3123, name: 'abc', ...},
{id: 3213, name: 'name', ...},
...
]

    filesForStorage.map((image, index) => {
          for (let i = 0; i < filesForStorage.length; i++) {
            for (let j = 0; j < filesForStorage.length; j++) {
              if (
                filesForStorage[i].name.split(".", 1) ===.   //.split('.', 1) is to not keep in consideration the file extension
                filesForStorage[j].name.split(".", 1)
              ) {
                console.log(
                  "----FILES HAVE THE SAME NAME " +
                    filesForStorage[i] +
                    " " +
                    filesForStorage[j]
                );
              }
            }
          }
```

Comment: Can you please share demo data for filesForStorage? A snippet would be wonderful.

Comment: Why do you run the 2 `for` loop in `Array.map`?

Comment: sure, the array and files are like so:

Array (10)
0 File {id: 0.6385802192553822, preview: "blob:http://localhost:3000/c857aaa7-51dd-4d8a-b209-810b9eaf9d34", uniqueId: "8Am0GOPEwATyd0ZkSHlG", name: "background1.jpeg", lastModified: 1624555546000, …}
1 File {live: true, id: 0.6403926850353915, preview: "blob:http://localhost:3000/e6db45de-cd66-408e-8c55-ac9a9968d504", uniqueId: "6hPqArZp1nNqruDIbh74", name: "image.gif", …}
2 File {id: 0.5735947653890782, preview: "blob:http://localhost:3000/697954be-50ee-46e6-ba38-8d6be54e7a9d", name: "background.png", ... }, ...]

Comment: I'm mapping because I'm doing this within the same function that I'm using to send each file to my db, I could also do this before.

Comment: @Jacopo Please format them and add them to the question

Comment: @Jacopo Also, please only add in code that is needed - eliminate any code that isn't needed for the question - thanks!

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong, but would't `filesForStorage[i].name.split(".", 1)` only return the file extension? So you are right now only comparing files by extension instead of name?

Comment: hey Michael, no that I have tested already and it works fine returning the name before the file extension :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `map` without returning anything makes it near on pointless. You could use `forEach` but that is equally pointless when you're using a double loop within - it means you would be looping once in the `foreach` (or `map` in your case) and then twice more within making for eye-wateringly bad performance.

What you're really trying to do is group your items by `name` and then pick any group with more than 1 element

```js
const filesForStorage = [
{id: 12323, name: 'name'},
{id: 3123, name: 'abc'},
{id: 3213, name: 'name'}
]

const grouped = Object.values(
  filesForStorage.reduce( (a,i) => {
    a[i.name] = a[i.name] || [];
    a[i.name].push(i);
    return a;
  },{})
);

console.log(grouped.filter(x => x.length>1).flat());
```

Comment: Cheers jamiec! Appreciate the answer!

Comment: Furthermore, could I splice(remove) the found files from the original array within reduce?

Comment: @Jacopo The ones with only a single eentry can just be `grouped.filter(x => x.length == 0).flat()` no need to change the original array at all.

Comment: I would recommend using a [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) or a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) instead of an Array

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript has several functions which perform "hidden" iteration.

- `Object.values` will iterate through an object of key-value pairs and collect all values in an array
- `Array.prototype.reduce` will iterate through an array and perform a computation for each element and finally return a single value
- `Array.prototype.filter` will iterate through an array and collect all elements that return true for a specified test
- `Array.prototype.flat` will iterate through an array, concatenating each element to the next, to create a new flattened array

All of these methods are wasteful as you can compute a collection of duplicates using a single pass over the input array. Furthermore, array methods offer O(n) performance at best, compared to O(1) performance of Set or Map, making the choice of arrays for this kind of computation eye-wateringly bad -

```js
function* duplicates (files) {
  const seen = new Set()
  for (const f of files) {
    if (seen.has(f.name))
      yield f
    else
      seen.add(f.name, f)
  }
}

const filesForStorage = [
  {id: 12323, name: 'foo'},
  {id: 3123, name: 'abc'},
  {id: 3213, name: 'foo'},
  {id: 4432, name: 'bar'},
  {id: 5213, name: 'qux'},
  {id: 5512, name: 'bar'},
]

for (const d of duplicates(filesForStorage))
  console.log("duplicate name found", d)
```

```
duplicate name found {
  "id": 3213,
  "name": "foo"
}
duplicate name found {
  "id": 5512,
  "name": "bar"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A nested loop can be very expensive on performance, especially if your array will have a lot of values. Something like this would be much better.

```js
filesForStorage = [
  { id: 12323, name: 'name' },
  { id: 3123, name: 'abc' },
  { id: 3213, name: 'name' },
  { id: 3123, name: 'abc' },
  { id: 3213, name: 'name' },
  { id: 3123, name: 'random' },
  { id: 3213, name: 'nothing' },
]

function sameName() {
  let checkerObj = {};
  let newArray = [];

  filesForStorage.forEach(file => {
   checkerObj[file.name] = (checkerObj[file.name] || 0) + 1;
  });

  Object.entries(checkerObj).forEach(([key, value]) => {
    if (value > 1) {
      newArray.push(key);
    }
  });

  console.log(newArray);

}

sameName();
```